# How can I dynamically load embedded videos from youtube using jwplayer and laravel 5.1?

Tags: jwplayer, laravel-5.1

I am using the laravel framework and I am trying to use JwPlayer to load the videos dynamically. I tried to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/WQWJdvRx.js"></script> {{-- jwplayer url + key may mv to head or footer --}}
<div id="myElement" title="{{ $video->subtitle }}"></div>
<script>

    function myFunction(){
        var div1 = document.getElementById("myElement");
        var attr = div1.getAttribute("title");


        jwplayer("myElement").setup({

            file: "attr",
            width: 640,
            height: 360,
            title:"title goes here",
            stretching:"fill",
            skin:{
                name:"stormtrooper"
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried using javascript to get the class name which is actually specific to a video. the variable attr then I tried using attr variable as my file path. But it's not working. Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are trying to run this?

Comment: @Ethan JWPlayer no I'm developing locally. I'm trying to make "file" dynamic. I have the paths stored in {{$post->subtitle}} But It wont work with the javascript

Comment: Looks like you got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. After I listened to your advice about removeing the quotest, I had to remove only the function it's parentesis and curly brackets. Then everything worked
so it went from this

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/WQWJdvRx.js"></script> 
<div id="myElement" title="{{ $video->subtitle }}"></div>
<script>

function myFunction(){
    var div1 = document.getElementById("myElement");
    var attr = div1.getAttribute("title");


    jwplayer("myElement").setup({

        file: "attr",
        width: 640,
        height: 360,
        title:"title goes here",
        stretching:"fill",
        skin:{
            name:"stormtrooper"
        }
    });
}
```

to this

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/WQWJdvRx.js"></script> 
<div id="myElement" title="{{ $video->subtitle }}"></div>
<script>

    var div1 = document.getElementById("myElement");
    var attr = div1.getAttribute("title");

    jwplayer("myElement").setup({

        file: attr,
        width: 640,
        height: 360,
        title:"title goes here",
        stretching:"fill",
        skin:{
            name:"stormtrooper"
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ah yes, the quotes would have done that. Glad you got it working!